# Confidence interval for these 2 questions.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I'm so lost here. I've studied the 2 examples in our notes but they don't seem to apply to these questions. Google is proving useless for me too. How can I find the confidence interval for question 3? I know this variance is biased but what does this change for the confidence interval? In class we did an example with (n-1) in the denominator so the variance was unbiased and we constructed a confidence interval using a Chi squared distributuion.

I am also lost on Question 2. Feels like I missed a lecture (I haven't). Any help or a link to relevent lecture notes would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Question 2

The point estimator for the mean is $\mu=\bar X$.

A confidence interval for the mean is $(\bar X-\epsilon_1,\bar X+ \epsilon_2)$

The rest is algebra.

### Question 3

[This](http://www.statlect.com/set_estimation_variance.htm) deals specifically with this problem.

Comment: I thought for question 2 I needed to use delta method?

Comment: I thought for question 2 I needed to use delta method?